# How do gardeners revive succulents and root them?

Tags: plant-health, succulents, repair

For example, I picked these up from some rather poorly maintained succulents, and want to revive the leaves, somehow.

I'm soaking them in water for a few hours, then putting half in water, half out, in hopes that they'll absorb some.

On one particularly large dried leaf, I cut off a centimeter of material from the base of the leaf, and put it in a vase, half submerged, with the cut down.

Is it even possible to revive from a condition where the leaves are brown, but are still flexible and contain moisture?

If it WAS possible, what would increase my chances of successfully reviving and rooting these leaves?

That is, for an answer relevant to a more general audience, what "leaf revival" options are most likely to work for a given common variety of succulent?

Comment: are you able to post the pictures so we can examine what is going on

Comment: I would be careful soaking them, simply because when over watered, they get limp and shrivel and could already be the reason they need revival. Yes @JStorage pic would be nice

Comment: We do need pictures please - currently, you haven't said which particular variety of succulent plant, and there are thousands of different ones

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what kind of succulents you want to root, but as a general rule the leaves need to be calloused when planted. Keep the cut area in contact with the air for a few days, then place the leaves in sand or soil and allow the potting medium to dry before watering again. I have tested this method on Echeveria, Peperomia ferreyrae and Sedum morganianum.

Some leaves generate new plants even if they were not previously calloused (Peperomia obtusifolia, Echeveria) but planted directly after cutting them.

As for the rooting in water method, I have never heard of a successful try.